# How to detect what subsystem is set?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

I want to have two main functions for GUI and Console mode.
Are there macros to detect what is set in Linker->System->SubSystem?

```
#ifdef ...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//...
}
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//...
}
#endif
```

`_CONSOLE` macro does not work for me.
And I don't use `WinMain` in my project. For GUI mode I also use `main`.

Comment: So you want to create two different applications for the same purpose? I'd rather prefer having one single application that can be controlled via command line parameter (my personal favourite), environment variable, config file or whatever else appears appropriate for you...

Comment: No. There is option Linker->System->SubSystem which allows to select run application as GUI or as Console. I want to test some code in console mode. That's why I want to have two main functions.

Comment: Create two separate projects providing different main function and using some shared codebase.

Comment: You realize that console programs use main and Windows programs use WinMain right?

Comment: @RetiredNinja No. Both are main(). (Qt project).